# Formatting number for 2 decimals - jquery

Tags: jquery, number-formatting

I have the following jquery function that auto populates a textbox based on the selection of a radio button option:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#DinnerYes").click(function() {
            $("#ThursdayDinnerFee").attr("value", 90);
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#DinnerNo").click(function() {
            $("#ThursdayDinnerFee").attr("value", 0);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The script works and it auto populates the textbox (ThursdayDinnerFee), but I want the numbers to appear in the textbox as 0.00 and 90.00. I also need to keep the format as number because they will be used in a credit card transaction. If someone could help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: please try searching before asking. Even on right side of this page under **Related** there are several answers you could have looked at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toFixed()` method like following.

```js
$("#ThursdayDinnerFee").val((90).toFixed(2))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ThursdayDinnerFee" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with pure JS (no jQuery needed):

Please take a look at the toFixed() method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Answer (score 0):

To keep the format you could use the [HTML5 Pattern-Tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute).